# What is the effect of HTML tag increase using Flexbox to SEO?

Tags: seo, html

As you all know when HTML tags increase, it negatively effects SEO. The ratio of the number of tags to content size needs to be below 0.

When i use Bootstrap or Flexbox-based discovery the number of HTML tags increase. This situation worries me quite frankly.

What do you think? I am open to suggestions and if there is a point that i have missed, i would appreciate it if you would inform me.

Comment: "As you all know..."  -- Actually, I don't know that.  Search engines tend to ignore markup and just focus on the content.  The number of HTML tags used around your content isn't a search engine ranking factor.  Why would it be?    The only time that I can think that it might hurt you to use more tags would be if you used so many it started to make your site perform worse.  Can you give a source for where you heard that?

Comment: I think you may have confused what(ever) you heard. The proper use of HTML generally helps your SEO/SERPs, and I'm not sure how you can have anything be "less than zero"... If your content size is below 0, then you have a blank page, right?  Now I'm confused, can you re-write your question?

Answer (score 1):

Although number of DOM elements does affect speed (screenshot comes from the Lighthouse), it is not something that should be sacrificed for good UX/UI.[image] Flexbox&Boostrap are popular for a reason, and there definitely are ways to handle them, when it comes to speed.